# Accessing jenkins secret inside pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

It might sound silly but I was trying to store my dockerhub password inside **Mange credentials** of jenkins as **Secret text** so that it can be accessed in the pipeline script.

**Here is the secret which I have created**

[image]

Here is a **pipeline script** where i trying to access the password using the **ID**

```
node {
    
stage("Docker Login"){
        sh 'docker login -u rahulwagh17 -p ${DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD}'
    } 
    
}
```

**But it always fails with -**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `withCredentials` method of jenkins' pipeline DSL.
Have a look here:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs
Every Job has it's pipeline syntax button available in it's dashboard:
`$JENKINs_URL/$YOUR_JOB/pipeline-syntax/`.
You can generate an adequate `withCredentials` blog there.

Comment: The article seems to have moved to https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/injecting-secrets